# Difference between identityId and token in AWS cognito

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

When using this in Lambda:

```
getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity
```

An identity and token gets returned.

What is the point of the identity and token? Which is for what?

Answer (score 1):

Identity id is a unique user identifier that Cognito creates for your user. This identifier remains constant if you link multiple logins for a same user.

Token on the other hand is an OpenId token which belongs to that user and is valid for a limited time. This token is exchanble for AWS credentials by calling either STS or `GetCredentialsForIdentity` API in Cognito Federated identity service.

There are multiple resources which explain the concepts of federated identity service.

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html
2. http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication